# why this PHP code is not working properly on remote host but works well on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, web-hosting

I use this code to get google page rank. it works perfect on my local host but it returns zero rank when I use it on my host(linux-php5).
code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>GPR</title>
<body>
<?php
function ZeroFill($a,$b){
  $z=hexdec(80000000);
  if($z&$a){
    $a=($a>>1);
    $a&=(~$z);
    $a|=0x40000000;
    $a=($a>>($b-1));
  }else{
    $a=($a>>$b);
  }
  return $a;
}
define('GOOGLE_MAGIC',0xE6359A60);
function Mix($a,$b,$c){
  $a-=$b;$a-=$c;$a^=(ZeroFill($c,13));
  $b-=$c;$b-=$a;$b^=($a<<8);
  $c-=$a;$c-=$b;$c^=(ZeroFill($b,13));
  $a-=$b;$a-=$c;$a^=(ZeroFill($c,12));
  $b-=$c;$b-=$a;$b^=($a<<16);
  $c-=$a;$c-=$b;$c^=(ZeroFill($b,5));
  $a-=$b;$a-=$c;$a^=(ZeroFill($c,3));
  $b-=$c;$b-=$a;$b^=($a<<10);
  $c-=$a;$c-=$b;$c^=(ZeroFill($b,15));
  return array($a,$b,$c);
}
function GoogleCH($url,$length=null,$init=GOOGLE_MAGIC){
  if(is_null($length)){
    $length=sizeof($url);
  }
  $a=$b=0x9E3779B9;
  $c=$init;
  $k=0;
  $len=$length;
  while($len>=12){
    $a+=($url[$k+0]+($url[$k+1]<<8)+($url[$k+2]<<16)+($url[$k+3]<<24));
    $b+=($url[$k+4]+($url[$k+5]<<8)+($url[$k+6]<<16)+($url[$k+7]<<24));
    $c+=($url[$k+8]+($url[$k+9]<<8)+($url[$k+10]<<16)+($url[$k+11]<<24));
    $mix=Mix($a,$b,$c);
    $a=$mix[0];$b=$mix[1];$c=$mix[2];
    $k+=12;
    $len-=12;
  }
  $c+=$length;
  switch($len){
    case 11:$c+=($url[$k+10]<<24);
    case 10:$c+=($url[$k+9]<<16);
    case 9:$c+=($url[$k+8]<<8);
    case 8:$b+=($url[$k+7]<<24);
    case 7:$b+=($url[$k+6]<<16);
    case 6:$b+=($url[$k+5]<<8);
    case 5:$b+=($url[$k+4]);
    case 4:$a+=($url[$k+3]<<24);
    case 3:$a+=($url[$k+2]<<16);
    case 2:$a+=($url[$k+1]<<8);
    case 1:$a+=($url[$k+0]);
  }
  $mix=Mix($a,$b,$c);
  return $mix[2];
}
function StringOrder($string){
  for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){$result[$i]=ord($string{$i});}
  return $result;
}
$url="Yahoo.com";
$server="toolbarqueries.google.com";

  $url="info:"."$url";
  $ch=trim(str_replace("-","",sprintf("6%u\n",GoogleCH(StringOrder($url)))));
  $res="http://$server/tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=$ch&features=Rank&q=$url";
  $data=@fopen("$res",r);
  if($data){
    while($line = fgets($data,1024)) {
      if(substr($line,0,7)=="Rank_1:"){$rankline = $line;}
    }
    fclose($data);
    if (isset($rankline)==false){$rankline="";};
    $pagerank = trim(substr($rankline,9,2));
    if($pagerank==""){$pagerank="0";}
    echo <<<HEADER


<table border=0>
HEADER;
echo "<td nowrap colspan=2><a href=\"http://".$url."\">".$url."</a></td>\n";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td nowrap>Pagerank:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td nowrap><b>".$pagerank."</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>\n";
$out = ''; 
echo $out;
echo <<<FOOTER
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</blockquote>
FOOTER;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is that? and how can I fix it?

Comment: this line:[$url="Yahoo.com";] show which url it is trying to get PR.

Comment: It's hard to tell, since your code is all jumbled, and you didn't include any information at all as to what you have done to debug the problem.  In addition, scraping for page rank this way is against Google's ToS.

Comment: Narrow-down your problem and then come back.

Comment: debug it until you find where it is failing.

Comment: Do you have errors enabled in your PHP.ini and with `error_reporting`?

Comment: Indeed, scrambled code like this and no comment is not going to help us, if you spent 1h looking at it, we'd need 3x the amount just to parse the code and understand where it is going... Please clean it up, narrow down the problem to something specific and we'll be able to better help you

Comment: How do you want us to read this code?

Answer (score 3):

Does your host allow you to use fopen for external URLs? You may need to use CURL.

First thing to do is verify that that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled on that host.

Comment: Even worse, some hosts don't allow scripts to make outgoing connections at all... in which case he's pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

what php versions are you using in your development and production environment?

check the following settings with emphasis on safe mode and [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php) remote resources:

- [safe_mode setting](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode)
- [open basedir restrictions](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)
- [fopen() with remote resources](http://www.php.net/manual/de/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)